# tinyMCE JQuery plugin - How do you set global config options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, tinymce

I'm new to tinyMCE and I like the jQuery plugin that comes in the latest version. However I'd like to set global options that would be used in every subsequent instance; for example themes and skins. Is this possible?

Edit.

Here is an example of the method I have used.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var config = {
        directionality : 'rtl'
    }

    $('#message').tinymce(
        $.extend({}, config, {
            directionality : "ltr"
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just create a defaults object containing the common options

and then use
$.extend(defaults, overrideOptions);

to put your overrides for each instance:

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tinymce.overrideDefaults()`:

```
tinymce.overrideDefaults({
   directionality: 'rtl'
});
```